# WordPress: add new post after user registration if role is subscriber

Tags: wordpress

I have the following working code to create a new CPT entry when users register, but now I need this to happen **only if the user has a subscriber role**. This registration is processed by WooCommerce. I have another form thru Theme My Login for another users role.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

$user_info = get_userdata($user_id);

// Here you can insert new post for registered users
$user_profile = array(
    'post_title' => 'Profile '.$user_id,
    'post_content' => '', 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => $user_id, 
    'post_type' => 'profiles'
);

// Insert the post into the database
$post_ID = wp_insert_post($user_profile);
if ($post_ID) {
    // update ACF fields
    update_field('field_5e0f8b80071a9', $user_info->first_name, $post_ID);
    update_field('field_5e107dcfddc77', $user_info->user_email, $post_ID);
  }
}
```

I have tried with

```
foreach( $user->roles as $role ) { 
    if ( $role === 'subscriber' ) {
     // code here
 }
}
```

and

```
if(in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $current_user->roles ) ) { 
  // code here
 }
```

with no success.

How can I detect the user role and only if it is subscriber have the wp_insert_post ?

UPDATE:
the actual function, still not working:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

$user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
$user_roles = $user_info->roles; // array with the user's roles


// Here you can insert new post for registered users
$user_profile = array(
    'post_title' => 'Profile '.$user_id,
    'post_content' => '', 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => $user_id, 
    'post_type' => 'profiles'
);


 if ( !empty( $user_roles ) && in_array( 'subscriber', $user_roles ) ) {

// Insert the post into the database
$post_ID = wp_insert_post($user_profile);
if ($post_ID) {
    // inserisco campi ACF
    update_field('field_5e0f8b80071a9', $user_info->first_name, $post_ID);
    update_field('field_5e107dcfddc77', $user_info->user_email, $post_ID);
     }
   }
 }
```

If I comment  *if ( !empty( $user_roles ) && in_array( 'subscriber', $user_roles ) )* it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it by using 'woocommerce_checkout_subscription_created' instead of 'user_register'

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the user info inside of the variable `$user_info`. In your `foreach` you are using the variable `$user` and in your if clause you are using `$current_user`. I think this is the reason it is not working.

I would suggest saving the roles of a user inside of a variable and use the `in_array` function. Your code can look like this:

```
...

$user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
$user_roles = $user_info->roles; // array with the user's roles

// Here you can insert new post for registered users
$user_profile = array(
    'post_title' => 'Profile '.$user_id,
    'post_content' => '', 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => $user_id, 
    'post_type' => 'profiles'
);

if ( !empty( $user_roles ) && in_array( 'subscriber', $user_roles ) ) {
    // Insert the post into the database
    $post_ID = wp_insert_post($user_profile);
}

...
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately still not working. I've edited my question adding the actual function, as you suggested.

Comment: So your code inserts the posts, no matter what user role the user has?

Comment: The code inserts the post only if there is no subscriber check.

If I add "if ( !empty( $user_roles ) && in_array( 'subscriber', $user_roles ) )" then no insert is made.

To be sure I've verified that the user is in the database and has subscriber role in wp_capabilities

Comment: Can you try with another role? This is strange, because the if needs to be true to run the `wp_insert_post`. I'm not quite sure if your user has a role in the moment it gets created... but then the wp_insert_post would never run.

Comment: It's just a suspect that I have, but maybe the role is not yet assigned right after the user_register action? I have no other explanation for this behaviour.

Comment: Can you try to `print_r ($user_roles);` before the if to see if there is a `subscriber` role in the console (use inspector of your browser)? To make sure the roles array is working fine.

Comment: Done. No track of role in the output. This is bizarre. Unless the role is assignad after the action.

Comment: Can you now try to force the role of subscriber using this before the if : `wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'subscriber') );` Beware: Your user gets the role of subscriber. I just want to make sure the if and insert post work correctly.

Comment: Makew sure to set the user_roles variable after updating the user ;)

Comment: Nothing. $user_roles = $user_info->roles; is not working. wp_update_user does work because I've tried assigning another (fake) role and I can see in the DB the this user has subscriber + the other (fake) role.

Comment: I even tried with  if(wcs_user_has_subscription($user_id)) { } with no success.

Comment: It is really strange, because if you have done it in the right order (first: update_user, second: get_userdata, third: save roles to array) I unfortunatelly don't know how the if can become false. May try to get rid of the priorities in the function: `add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save' );`